# Redis Pub/Sub persistence

Tags: redis, message-queue

I am working on redis SMQ persistence. My questions here is, While publisher publishing the messages, consumer has stopped suddenly. When consumer connects again, is it possible to subscribe messages from where it has stopped?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No - Redis' Pub/Sub has no persistence, and once a message has been published, it is sent only to the connected subscribed clients. Afterwards, the message is gone forever.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve persistence by anyways creating heartbeat and garbage collector methods?

Comment: Anything should be possible in theory, but it is usually simpler to use the right tool for the job. If you need stronger assurances, look into the upcoming Stream Redis data structure.

Comment: Hi @ItamarHaber, if a subscriber is disconnected, then I re-connect it. Whether subscribers can get the after msg (which are not got from any subscriber) from publishers or not? Does Redis use the queue to store that pending msg? +1 From my respect.

Answer (score 3):

With standard Pub/Sub you can use Lua scripts to persist your message. You need to check whether you have a listener on channel or not. If not then storing your message with channel key on redis . When the subscriber cames back it checks if there is anything for him based on channel key. Second option is to use [Redis Stream](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro). Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/forkfork/c27d741650dd65631578771ab264dd2c).

Answer (score 0):

Plz use 2 redis connections: 1 pubsub, second - LPOP/RPOP